# Can I have Google C++ Testing Framework assert that the process does *not* die?

Tags: c++, googletest

The Google C++ Testing Framework ([gtest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/)) provides "[death tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#How_to_Write_a_Death_Test)" where I can assert that a test caused a (forked) process to exit, and I can apply a predicate on the exit code. Is there a way that I can assert that the process **did not exit**?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the rest of my tests run even if one of them dies due to (for example) an access violation.

The test might look something like this. Note that ASSERT_NO_EXIT does not exist.

```
GTEST_TEST(MyTests, MyTest)
{
    GTEST_ASSERT_NO_EXIT({
        int val1 = 1;
        int val2 = 2;
        GTEST_ASSERT_EQ(val2, val1 + 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick.

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GTEST_ASSERT_NO_DEATH(statement) \
    ASSERT_EXIT({{ statement } ::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }, ::testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "")
```

I was able to use the above macro as follows

```
GTEST_TEST(MyTests, MyTest)
{
    GTEST_ASSERT_NO_DEATH({
        int val1 = 1;
        int val2 = 2;
        GTEST_ASSERT_EQ(val2, val1 + 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: You could also just write the test. If the test process crashes, I think one can assume something went wrong :)

Comment: This test will also pass if the statement under test calls exit(0);.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old post, but this was just what I needed because I was writing a regression test that a segmentation fault did NOT recur in the latest build, and previously the segmentation fault was crashing the entire Google Test process, so while this solution would trigger "pass" if the process exited with 0, there is no chance of that and this was able to detect the segfault and mark the test as "fail" without stopping the rest of the testsuite.